# Temporary nodes in ConcurrentHashMap Java 8

Tags: java, hashmap, java.util.concurrent

Looking at `java.util.ConcurrentHashMap.putVal()`, I came across some conditions that checks if any object(node) in array has `hashcode()` as -ve value. This code, for eg:

```java
    for (Node<K,V>[] tab = table;;) {
        Node<K,V> f; int n, i, fh;
        if (tab == null || (n = tab.length) == 0)
            tab = initTable();
        else if ((f = tabAt(tab, i = (n - 1) & hash)) == null) {
            if (casTabAt(tab, i, null,
                         new Node<K,V>(hash, key, value, null)))
                break;                   // no lock when adding to empty bin
        }
        else if ((fh = f.hash) == MOVED) // THIS HERE???
            tab = helpTransfer(tab, f);
```

note that it checks for `fh==MOVED` and `MOVED` is -1, so what objects(nodes) have negative hashcode() in CHM?

Further reading the documentation, it says there could be 3 types of nodes could be there(first in bin) apart from real nodes and their hashcode() could be among:

```java
    static final int MOVED     = -1; // hash for forwarding nodes
    static final int TREEBIN   = -2; // hash for roots of trees
    static final int RESERVED  = -3; // hash for transient reservations
```

I can understand first is for tempory reference while resizing map but I can not seem to understand the usage of -2 and -3 hashcode() . Help?

Answer (score 2):

`TREEBIN` is used to mark a `TreeBin` and `RESERVED` marks `ReservationNode` used in `compute` and `computeIfAbsent` methods. These hash code can be use to determine what is the type of a bin node.

There are 4 types of bin node, Node with `hash >= 0`, TreeBin with `hash == TREEBIN`, ForwardingNode with `hash == MOVED`, ReservationNode with `hash == RESERVED`.

These nodes with different hash code are used to avoid concurrent issue. Although we can use `instanceof` to distinguish them from each other, it's more effecient to distinguish `Node` from others because they are all subclass of `Node`. For taking acount of efficiency, this hash code design is useful.

Further more, there are other reason for creating these types. For example, compared with `HashMap`, we have no need to `moveRootToFront`(would cause problem when other thread is finding) after using `TreeBin`, because `TreeBin` stores the root of the tree.